# Jenkins Server - Issues with setting URL

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to set up an internal Jenkins server for our QA team and facing some issues with the server URL. This is inside a corporate network and all sort of firewall and proxy settings are in place, however we need to access the server only with in our internal network. This server runs from a Mac Mini. I was able to install and access the server without any issues using localhost:8080.

1. I tried to set a custom URL (something like testjenkins.local:8080)under the Manage Jenkins option and never was able to access the server. The only option worked for me is with the IP address (IP:8080). I was able to access the server from other machines in the network using this URL.
2. The real problem with the above setup is that the machine IP changes(I am not able to make it static), and hence wont be able to get an always working URL.

Highly appreciate if any one guide me in the wright direction.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but I assume you would need a nameserver that collaborates with your DHCP server, something that for you is propably more difficult than getting a fixed IP. A possible workaround: configure your DHCP client to ask always for a specific IP. If you are lucky and your DHCP is friendly, you may get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have a dynamic IP on your server, a good alternative would be using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Ngrok can expose the port 8080 of that server to the internet via secure tunnels, and you can access it via an URL, so changes in the IP won't affect it.

However, ngrok exposes the server to the whole Internet. To make it accessible only for your team you can add authentication in both ngrok tunnel and Jenkins server (would it work for you?).